# Change view using a button click in WinUI 3

Tags: c#, .net, winui-3

In WinUI 3 I want to change the view to a `SecondaryView` after a button click. The view change works flawlessly if I just add it to my code. But as soon as it happens in a Button Click function the app crashes. I am using the `Template Studio for WinUI` template to do this. The relative code is as follows:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
   <TextBlock Text="Main Page"/>
   <Button Content="Press" Click="Button_Clicked"/>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
public MainPage()
{
    ViewModel = App.GetService<MainViewModel>();
    InitializeComponent();
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SecondaryViewModel).FullName); // WORKS
}

private void Button_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SecondaryViewModel).FullName); // DOESN'T WORK
}
```

The exception I get is

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
     UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
     {
          if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
     };
#endif
```

This is all right from the template, barely changing anything. I tried it in my own code first before trying the template and got the same error. Is there any way to change the view on a button click?

Comment: Is there a NavigationService reference in the constructor or MainPage?

Comment: I'm new to .NET and not sure what the constructor is, but there is nothing else in MainPage and searching through the Class files I only see it showing up in the `DefaultActivationHandler` and the `NavigationService.cs` file itself, besides the line for `INavigationService` I added to `MainPage.xaml.cs`

Comment: According to the comments of your previous question, you should go with a ShellPage in compact mode to mimic the behaviour of a mobile app.

Comment: WinUI Template Studio uses MS Community Toolkit. Maybe starting with WinUI3 apps is not the best way to learn .Net. Of course is just a suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I know WinUI 3 isn't the best place to start but I've learned a ton in a short time. So it sounds like there isn't a fix for this issue then, correct?

Comment: @RickyKresslein I just tried what you did (navigation with a button on a TemplateStudio project) and works without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the `_navigationService`.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public MainViewModel ViewModel
    {
        get;
    }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
        ViewModel = App.GetService<MainViewModel>();
        InitializeComponent();
        _navigationService = App.GetService<INavigationService>();  // This line is missing.
        _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SecondaryViewModel).FullName);
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, Microsoft.UI.Xaml.RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _navigationService.NavigateTo(typeof(SecondaryViewModel).FullName);
    }
}
```